# Retrofit upload file with key name

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

i want to upload image/file to server .so it should contain keyname and against that key it should hold Multipart

```
@Multipart
@POST("/upload/")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part filePart);
```

i am doing this way but in this key where i can define param key and part as a value .
so "value1" : mutltipart

i am creating file

```
      RequestBody requestFile =
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), File);
   multiPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload_file", compressedFile.getName(), requestFile);
```

is this right ? and most of this time it giving me sockettimeout event i have set timeout for 10min

in volley i have sending as byte[] is any way i can send

Comment: have look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40607862/retrofit-throwing-an-exception-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-only-one-en/40608320#40608320 . and watch out what mistake you did .