# Upload Image to server using Retrofit2 POST request

Tags: android, image-uploading, multipartform-data, retrofit2

I want to upload my gallery image to server using Retrofit2. API has 1 param which contains flie as form data & another param is header with key. When I am uploading image to server I get File not found message from server. I am sending proper file name but I don't know why it is giving so.Can anyone help me to solve.Below is my code.

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserProfileActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Updating Data");
        progressDialog.show();

        //Create Upload Server Client
        ApiService service = RetroClient.getApiService();

        //File creating from selected URL
        File file = new File(imgDecodableString);
        Log.d("TAG","file="+file.getName());
        // create RequestBody instance from file
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
        MultipartBody.Part body =
                MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestFile);

        Call<com.example.datamodel.Response> resultCall = service.uploadImage(loginHash,body);

        resultCall.enqueue(new Callback<com.example.datamodel.Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<com.example.datamodel.Response> call, retrofit2.Response<com.example.datamodel.Response> response) {
                com.example.datamodel.Response mBean = response.body();
                if(null != mBean)
                {
                    Log.d("TAG","RS="+mBean.getMessage());
                    Log.d("TAG","RS="+mBean.getData().getvImage());
                }

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<com.example.datamodel.Response> call, Throwable t) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Log.d("TAG", "fail=" + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

RetroClient.java

```
public class RetroClient {
public RetroClient() {

}
private static Retrofit getRetroClient() {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConstants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
}

public static ApiService getApiService() {
    return getRetroClient().create(ApiService.class);
}}
```

ApiService.java

```
public interface ApiService {
@Multipart
@POST("api/User/uploadUserProfilePhoto")
Call<Response> uploadImage(@Header("vLoginHash") String vLoginHash,@Part MultipartBody.Part file);}
```

In logcat I am getting File not found message from server. Anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use this may be it help http://stackoverflow.com/a/40608320/5305430

Comment: @sushildlh i have already done this and also changes MediaType.parse("image/*") but still same error

Answer (score 0):

Try without multipart

```
 @POST("/api/name.jpg")
        Call<Object> upload(
                @Header("header_name") String authorization,
                @Body RequestBody body);
```

In OnActivityREsult

```
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {

                Bitmap photo = null;
             if(requestCode==REQUEST_GALLERY){
                    try {
                        photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
                if(photo!=null){
                    Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getActivity(), photo);
                    // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
                    File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
                   RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
            apimy.upload(header value,requestBody).enque...            
                }
            }

 public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        assert cursor != null;
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }
```

This code works fine for me.

Comment: Getting Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.

Comment: remove @Multipart in your interface above post line

Comment: I have removed it but same result.

Comment: in req body .parse(star/star)

Comment: can you edit with uploadImage() method? I have tried but it not working. So need to see whats is in your method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129096/discussion-between-arpan-sharma-and-nitish-patel).

Comment: .parse(*/*) never works. It goes into infinite loop.